# Relation between Precision Time Protocol and self-clocking signals

Tags: layer1

I'm quite confused between time synchronization and clock synchronization.

[Self-clocking signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-clocking_signal) is used to tell the receiver at which rate sender sending the bits so that it can read the bits at the same rate (to avoid data loss).

[Precision Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol) is a protocol used to synchronize clocks throughout a computer network. On a local area network, it achieves clock accuracy in the sub-microsecond range, making it suitable for measurement and control systems.

are both doing the same job here? is Self-clocking signal still needed even if the network perfectly synced by PTP mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PTP runs on top of Ethernet (data link layer) or higher. Accordingly, it has no relation to the clocks used on the physical layer. The latter may require very tight *relative* synchronization of transmitter/receiver in the picosecond range (for 25 GBd PHYs) but no *absolute* synchronization (wall time) at all.

Comment: so physical layer always need some sort of line code mechanism (example: Manchester code) to embed clock to actual data so that receiver can decode at the same rate. is it right?

Comment: Yes - since physical-layer transmissions are generally self-clocking, they require an appropriate line code. The receiver must be able to sync to the transmitter's clock in order to recover the data. Note that 10 Mbit/s with Manchester is archaic, 8b/10b and 64b/66b are widely used today.